# Вторая цена в вариативном товаре Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, variable

уважаемые эксперты WordPress.

Имеем следующую ситуацию: в нашем магазине реализована 2-ая цена для вариативного товара. Вот код который используется и работает:

```
// Backend Variation - Add / Display MRSP Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_variation_options_pricing_msrp', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_pricing_msrp( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_msrp_'.$loop,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
        'class' => 'short wc_input_price',
        'label' => __( 'Цена за комплект', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'value' => wc_format_localized_price( get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_msrp', true ) ),
        'data_type' => 'price',
    ) );
}

// Backend Variation - Save MRSP Field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_pricing_msrp',10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_pricing_msrp( $variation_id, $loop ){
    if( isset($_POST['_msrp_'.$loop]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_msrp', wc_clean( wp_unslash( str_replace( ',', '.', $_POST['_msrp_'.$loop] ) ) ) );
}

// Frontend Variation - MRSP display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">' . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) .
        '<span class="msrp-price">' . wc_price( $msrp ) . '</span></div>' . $data['price_html'];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

На фронтенде это выглядит так при выборе цвета двери:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит небольшая задача:

1. Необходимо поменять местами цены - нижнюю цену подвинуть вверх, а верхнюю опустить вниз. Если смотреть на скриншот - сверху будет 87.18 р., а снизу 155.22 р.
2. Добавить небольшой текст перед второй ценой (перед 87.18 р.)

Должно получиться так:

**Полотно: 87.18 р.**

**Комплект: 155.22 р.**

Был бы очень признателен за помощь.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поменять содержимое этого if? `if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">' . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) .
        '<span class="msrp-price">' . wc_price( $msrp ) . '</span></div>' . $data['price_html'];
    }`

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю - этот код отвечает за вторую цену, и она меня устраивает полностью. Мне нужно к основной цене вариации добавить текст перед ценой....а я не программист....должен быть примерно такой же код, только отвечающий за основную цену вариации.